# Dynamic HTML Table not accessing javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have built the HTML table where you can dynamically add / delete rows. Adding and deleting rows work well, the problem I am having is the table consists of three columns and the columns have drop downs in them. I have created a script were the first column dropdown will get values from the database and the third column's dropdown gets the value from the database on what was selected on the first dropdown. It works on the first row but not the appended rows when you click add row button. Note: I have used some old code and poor sql programming standards. I used them just to understand and I will take it from there with the necessary changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("getSolution.php", success = function(data) {
    var options = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
    }

    $(".meetingPlace").append(options);
    $(".meetingPlace").change();
  });

  $(".meetingPlace").change(function() {

    $.getJSON("getSolutionPrice.php?make=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data) {
      var options = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
      }

      $("#costing").html("");
      $("#costing").append(options);
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-borderless table-header-bg test" id="quoteTable1">
  <tr><span class="center-block text-center" style="font-weight: bold">Inital Fee</span>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">D</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 50%">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Units</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 35%">Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="js-select form-control meetingPlace" name="initial_solution[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">
      <select class="js-select form-control" id="example-select2" name="initial_quantity[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="js-select form-control" id="costing" name="initial_solution1[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-group text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary push-5-r push-10 plusbtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Solution</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-danger push-5-r push-10 minusbtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete Solution</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plusbtn').click(function() {

      $(".test").append('<tr><td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"></td><td><select class="js-select form-control meetingPlace" name="initial_solution[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."></select></td><td class="hidden-xs"><select class="js-select form-control" id="example-select2" name="initial_quantity[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></td><td><select class="js-select form-control" id="costing" name="initial_solution1[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."></select></td></tr>');
    });
    $('.minusbtn').click(function() {
      if ($(".test tr").length != 2) {
        $(".test tr:last-child").remove();
      } else {
        alert("You cannot delete first row");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = "";

    $.getJSON("getSolution.php", function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }

        $(".meetingPlace").append(options);
        $(".meetingPlace").change();

    });




    //options = "<option>Juice</option><option>22</option><option>33</option><option>44</option><option>55</option><option>66</option>";
    //$('.test tr:eq(1)').find('.meetingPlace').html("");
    //$('.test tr:eq(1)').find('.meetingPlace').append(options);

    $('.plusbtn').click(function () {
        $(".test").append('<tr><td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"></td><td><select class="js-select form-control meetingPlace" name="initial_solution[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."></select></td><td class="hidden-xs"><select class="js-select form-control" id="example-select2" name="initial_quantity[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></td><td><select class="js-select form-control costing"  name="initial_solution1[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."></select></td></tr>');

        var options = "";

        $.getJSON("getSolution.php", function (data) {

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }

            $('.test tr:last').find('.meetingPlace').html("");
            $('.test tr:last').find('.meetingPlace').append(options);

        });

    });


    $('.minusbtn').click(function () {
        if ($(".test tr").length != 2) {
            $(".test tr:last-child").remove();
        } else {
            alert("You cannot delete first row");
        }
    });




    $('#quoteTable1').on('change', '.meetingPlace', function () {

        var objSelect = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').find('.costing');
        var options = "";

        $.getJSON("getSolutionPrice.php?make="+$(this).val(), function (data) {

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }
            $(objSelect).html("");
            $(objSelect).append(options);
        });
    });
});
```

```
<body>
    <table class="table table-striped table-borderless table-header-bg test" id="quoteTable1">
  <tr><span class="center-block text-center" style="font-weight: bold">Inital Fee</span>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">D</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 50%">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Units</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 35%">Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="js-select form-control meetingPlace" name="initial_solution[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">
      <select class="js-select form-control" id="example-select2" name="initial_quantity[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="js-select form-control costing"  name="initial_solution1[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-group text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary push-5-r push-10 plusbtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Solution</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-danger push-5-r push-10 minusbtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete Solution</button>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your codes above works on making the table dynamic. The drop down on the first column and the drop down on the third column are dependent on database. The first column drop down will have a normal select statement to fill the product names the third drop down will have the price of first drop down selection. My code the first row works but every new row added it does not run the script, Any ideas

Comment: Hi Shriya R, we getting some where. I changed the script and everytime a change happens on first drop down an alert pops up even when I add a new row. I added multiple row and made a change on all drop downs on first column and an alert pops up. So I took out the alert code and added my getting price script. It works but when the multiple dropdowns on the first column make a change only the first drop down on the third column take the change.

Comment: I want for eg: if I select juice on the first row dropdown on the first column then the first row drop down on the third drop down must get the juice price and if second row cake is selected then the second row drop down must take the cake price etc. But what happening now is the second row selected value is putting the price on the first row and removing the price of the first row selected value. Basically all the changes are only happening on the first row third column drop down

Comment: Yes it works, Thank you. One more question. How will I implement it to get the values from database?

Comment: set options value with the db value

Comment: I added a piece of php in the script tags in your options variable to load the products in the optiona tag and it worked. I tried adding the get prices script but in your options variable on the on change funtion but does not work. How would I get the price on the third dropdown to match the product that was selected on the first dropdown?

Comment: let me show the sample data showing on the third select

Comment: <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM products"; $result = mysql_query($query, $connection); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<option>".$row["productName"]."</option>"; }?>"; I have this php code in the two options variable before the minusbtn click function and it loads the dropdowns with the products

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want me to give you some products with prices?

Comment: $('#quoteTable1').on('change','.meetingPlace',function () {

        $.getJSON("getSolutionPrice.php?make=" + $(this).val(), success = function (data){
            var options = "";

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }

            //$(".costing").html("");
            $(".costing").append(options);
        });
    }) This is my current script that I use to link

Comment: if (isset($_GET['make'])) {

    $product = $_GET["make"];

    $query = "SELECT productCost FROM products WHERE productName LIKE '{$product}'";
    $data = mysql_query($query, $con);

    $price = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        array_push($price, $row['productCost']);
    }

    echo json_encode($price);
} This is the php file that the script calls

Comment: Thank you. I have ran the code and made the changes for the database. I have replaced juice.json with getSolution.php - This php file gets all the products. When I ran the code the drop down did not get the values until i removed "juice" from the for loop and in between the option tags, And now it is getting the values. But the third drop down in the third column is not getting the price. Please see below the changes I made to your script

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes that you need to do, since the rows are created dynamically you can use `event` delegation for registering the change event handler. then in teh change event handler you need to find the second select element in relation to the one changed - ie in the same row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("getSolution.php", success = function(data) {
    var options = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
    }

    $(".meetingPlace").append(options);
    $(".meetingPlace").change();
  });

  $("#quoteTable1").on('change', '.meetingPlace', function() {
    var $select = $(this);

    $.getJSON("getSolutionPrice.php?make=" + $select.val(), function(data) {
      var options = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
      }

      $select.closest('tr').find(".costing").html(options);
    });
  })
});
```

Since ID of an element must be unique use `costing` as a class not as ID.

Comment: @CoderJoe did you change teh id to class

Comment: Yes I did. @Arun P Johny

Comment: @CoderJoe did you see whether the change event handler is getting called

Comment: Yes @Arun P Johny. Does not even load the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Event Delegation.

This code:

```
$(".meetingPlace").change(function()
```

says: assign the function to all ".meetingPlace" elements *that exist at the time this code runs*.

Your new rows *don't* exist when that is called, so they don't get the event.

Instead, use:

```
$(document).on("change", ".meetingPlace", function() ...
```

which will apply to **all existing and all new** ".meetingPlace" elements.

The will fix the issue raised in the question, but there may be other issues with your code.